# Create faceted graph in R, keeping other points as greyed out

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I have some data (`AllPCA`) that is divided by site. I have used `qplot (PC1, PC2, data=AllPCA, colour=Population, facets=~Population) + scale_colour_manual (values=cbbPalette)` to facet a scatterplot of two variables by site.

Example AllPCA:

```
ID PC1 PC2 Population
Syd1 0.0185 0.0426 Sydney
Was1 0.0167 0.0415 Washington
Rea1 0.0182 0.0431 Reading
Aar1 0.0183 0.0427 Aarhus
```

This works fine, but only gives the data from each site in each of the windows.

I would like to create the same plot, but keeping the rest of the data in each facetted plot, just greyed out. Can you help?

Comment: It's quite simple (you only need to duplicate all observations). If you made your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059) it would be easy to show you how.

Comment: Apologies, the actual dataset is huge, so not really possible to provide a good example of it.

Comment: Have you read the FAQ I linked to? Simply make a small toy example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use two `geom_point()` calls. In first I use `data=AllPCA[,-4]` - this is your data without column `Population` and set `color="grey"`. So all points will be plotted in all facets in grey. Then I add second `geom_point()` with all data and `color=Population`. This will add only points in facets corresponding to each `Population` in separate colors (when `facet_wrap()` is used).

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=AllPCA[,-4],aes(PC1,PC2),color="grey")+
  geom_point(data=AllPCA,aes(PC1,PC2,color=Population))+
  facet_wrap(~Population)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate your data several times:

```
n <- length(unique(AllPCA[["Population"]]))
dat <- do.call(rbind, rep(list(AllPCA), n))
```

Create new columns for (a) facetting and (b) colour:

```
dat[["Population2"]] <- rep(AllPCA[["Population"]], each = n)
dat[["PopulationMatch"]] <- with(dat, Population == Population2)
```

Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(PC1, PC2, data = dat, colour = PopulationMatch, facets = ~ Population2) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("grey", "black"))
```

[image]